# Save Data in C++, Load from Python - Recommended Data Formats

Tags: python, c++, hdf5

I have a ROS/CPP simulator that saves large amounts of data to a rosbag (around 90 MB). I want to read this data frequently from Python and since reading rosbags is slow and cumbersome, I currently have another python script that reads the rosbag and saves the relevant contents to a HDF5 file.

It would be nice though to be able to just save the data from the simulator directly (in C++) and then read it from my scripts (in Python). So I was wondering which data format I should use. 
It should be:

1. Fast to load from Python
2. Be compact (so ideally a binary of some sort)
3. Be easy to use

You might be wondering why I don't just save to HDF5 from my C++ simulator, but it just doesn't seem to be easy. There is basically nothing on forums such as Stackoverflow and the [HDF5 Group website](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support) is opaque, seems to have some complicated licensing and very poor examples. I just want something quick and dirty that I can get running this afternoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it is a high-level language (similar to SQL) to manage HDF5 files. Amongst others, HDFql supports C++ and Python. There are some examples that illustrates how to use HDFql in these languages [here](http://www.hdfql.com/examples).

Comment: Hi @SOG, I have been trying to get HDFql running on my system, but been running into problem after problem (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780098/linking-external-hdfql-library-in-cmake). Perhaps you would consider dropping by on that post and giving some advice? Many thanks!

Comment: @MrSquid just dropped a comment in the suggested post.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions that can be useful for your problem :

- `LV`: Length Value that you can store directly in binary into a file.
- `JSON`: This does not add many data more than you need, and there are many libraries in Python or C++ that can simplify you the work

Comment: JSON is going to be too bulky for me. If I save the data as JSON it winds up being substantially bigger than HDF, my files are pretty huge as it is...

Comment: I see... The best thing would be LV for you so !

Answer (score 0):

[Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) is an option with language bindings in C++ and Python, though it might be more time investment than quick/dirty running this afternoon.